# drawing rectangle in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to draw a rectangle using android opengl. The rectangle will be formed within a colorful background. After running the code i can see a background but no rectangle inside it.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        
    gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.5f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       
    float[] vertices=
    {
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,               
    };
    short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };     
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);       
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    ShortBuffer indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       
    gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.7f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
{
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,
    (float) width / (float) height,
    0.1f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

}
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) 
{
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);     

}
```

what's wrong in my code? Any suggestions please....

Comment: Are you sure about the winding order of the triangles? You might want to disable culling for testing purposes.

Answer (score 11):

Initializing the Buffers in your onDrawFrame method doesn't look right.

I suggest you create a basic Rectangle class with vertices and indices as fields:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private float vertices[]={
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,1.0f,0.0f
    };


    private short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

    public Rectangle(){
        ByteBuffer vbb  = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl){
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

}
```

Add a Rectangle field to your Renderer and initialize it in the Renderer's constructor:

```
public MyOpenGLRenderer() {
    mRectangle = new Rectangle();
}
```

and call the Rectangle's draw method in your Renderer's onDrawFrame method:

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //...
    mRectangle.draw(gl);
}
```

Follow the first 3 parts of [this tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) for a complete solution to how it can be done.

Comment: I can't exactly say what it wrong with the code in the Question, but this answer looks like the sane solution in any case. The Buffers should be allocated once, not every frame.

Comment: thanks, i did it for drawing lines and triangle with the same procedure but problems with the rectangle.

Comment: @Tauhidul Alam. You might want to have a look at this tutorial as well - it goes through how to draw a rectangle on screen in section 2.4: :http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html

Comment: @Tauhidul Alam. Glad to hear it was of help:)

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson could you give me a hint on how I could draw the rectangles in a different color ? Just simple argb no crazy texture.

Comment: @stefple Have a look at 'Example 3 - Color' in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Your triangles are behind the near plane. The camera is at z=0, the near plane is 0.1f, and your triangles are at z=0.

Either draw the triangles further along the -z axis, or set up a camera with z > 0.1f.

Also to draw a rectangle with GL_TRIANGLES, you need 6 vertices, not 4. You should still see something though.

Comment: thanks, i tried it with 6 vertices but no progress. Any reference please.